# Does Apache create .htaccess file on startup

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Working with Docker and a PHP application.  Something (assuming Apache) is creating the following .htaccess file in webroot on container start up.

```
/var/www/html# cat .htaccess 
Deny from all
```

I delete the .htaccess file and my application works properly. Then shows up again when I start the container.  This is a basic Debian Stretch / Apache / PHP 7 image with my PHP code added to it.

Looking for reason or module that is doing this.

Edit: The Dockerfile https://pastebin.com/VDTFYJ0X

Comment: Have you examined the dockerfile? Also, you can remove that in *your* Dockerfile.

Comment: I have many times, posted above.  I have added a remove in the docker-init which is run via CMD on container start.

If Apache or any module is not doing this I'll have to look elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache is **not** automatically creating .htaccess files.
I highly assume that your problems is caused by docker.
Try checking your Dockerfile.

Comment: Ok.  I'll look elsewhere.  I noticed I'm installing running composer in the webroot, could be possibility.

Answer (score 0):

The program creating .htaccess file is Composer. Note this issue:

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/5816

Best to set `COMPOSER_HOME` to something other than the web root.